# How to avoid spaces in echo when it is split into multiple lines

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a very long string to be printed by `echo` command. By doing so I want it to be perfectly indented.
I am trying this and it is perfectly working fine

```
echo "This is a very long string. An"\
"d it is printed in one line"

Output:
This is a very long string. And it is printed in one line
```

But as I try to indent it properly as the echo statement is also indented. It adds an extra space.

```
echo "This is a very long string. An"\
    "d it is printed in one line"

Output:
This is a very long string. An d it is printed in one line
```

I can't find any working response which will do this perfectly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem here is that you are giving two arguments to `echo`, and its default behaviour is to prints them back with a space in between:

```
$ echo "a"             "b"
a b
$ echo "a" "b"
a b
$ echo "a"\
>           "b"
a b
```

---

If you want to have full control on what you are printing, use arrays with `printf`:

```
lines=("This is a very long string. An"
       "d it is printed in one line")
printf "%s" "${lines[@]}"
printf "\n"
```

This will return:

```
This is a very long string. And it is printed in one line
```

Or as [suggested by 123 in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38765151/how-to-avoid-spaces-in-echo-when-it-is-split-into-multiple-lines/38765266#comment64902617_38765266), use `echo` also with the array setting IFS to null:

```
# we define the same array $lines as above

$ IFS=""
$ echo "${lines[*]}"
This is a very long string. And it is printed in one line
$ unset IFS
$ echo "${lines[*]}"
This is a very long string. An d it is printed in one line
#                             ^
#                             note the space
```

From the [Bash manual → 3.4.2. Special Parameters](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Special-Parameters):

> *****
>
> ($*) Expands to the positional parameters, starting from one. When the expansion is not within double quotes, each positional parameter expands to a separate word. In contexts where it is performed, those words are subject to further word splitting and pathname expansion. When the expansion occurs within double quotes, it expands to a single word with the value of each parameter separated by the first character of the IFS special variable. That is, "$*" is equivalent to "$1c$2c…", where c is the first character of the value of the IFS variable. **If IFS is unset, the parameters are separated by spaces. If IFS is null, the parameters are joined without intervening separators.**

Interesting reading: [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/40596).

Comment: Thanks. I am doing that. Just for the record, is it possible using `echo` ?

Comment: @molecule well you can do something like `for line in "${lines[@]}"; do;   echo -n "$line"; done`. But it is a bit ugly, isn't it?

Comment: yeah, ugly indeed. Thanks mate

Comment: @molecule for echo you can just change the IFS to nothing, and then print the array using `${lines[*]}`